# Apache camel blueprint MS SQL datasource on karaf

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-camel, datasource, karaf

I am trying to access a MS SQL database with apache camel. I am building it with maven as a bundle and deploy it on apache karaf.To do this I got the following in my blueprint.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource">
     <property name="url" value="" />
     <property name="user" value="paygate" />
     <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/mssqlDatasource" />
    </service-properties>
</service>
```

But now I am getting the following in my karaf logs

```
missing requirement [1374.6] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx)
```

This is the class that also was generated when creating the datasource in karaf with 'jdbc:create'.

Why doesn't karaf find that class?

Comment: Have you tried to install the jtds jar as a bundle , using the command : install -s  wrap:mvn: net.sourceforge.jtds /jtds/1.3.0,   change version number to match your jar

Comment: No I didn't - but it worked thanks :)

Comment: @AshokNanda no I did not- but it worked? So did it work or not?

Comment: I did not try that before and it worked for me

Comment: @Namphibian the osgi command works, will add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the jtds jar as a bundle , using the command :

```
install -s wrap:mvn: net.sourceforge.jtds /jtds/1.3.0
```

Change version number to match your jar version, that will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is the MSSQL datasource,

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

Then you should install dbcp and jtds dependency in karaf container. It is working fine.